# browserfield finished loading in blackberry

Tags: blackberry, browserfield

Please can anyone help me with my issue - what is the way to know that browserfield2 has finished loading in Blackberry.
I need to set some options after loading. Does browserfield2 have some methods to show that?

Answer (score 8):

Here is some code that will get you started.

```
BrowserField browserField = new BrowserField();
 BrowserFieldListener listener = new BrowserFieldListener() {
     public void documentLoaded(BrowserField browserField, Document document) throws Exception
     {
         // the document has loaded, do something ...
     }
 }
 browserField.addListener( listener );
```

Comment: Helped enough to count towards an answer?

Comment: To accept, you should "check" the answer (so the check becomes green), not only up vote.